# Check if firewall is turned on Linux throught C library

Tags: c, linux, firewall

I would like to find out how I can check if the firewall is turned on/off through a C/C++ library. Are there some library for this purpose? Thank you.

Comment: What "firewall"? You mean that there are rules in an iptable? What rules should that be then?

Comment: Only I would need to check if there are any firewall turning on/off ports

Comment: Considering the "firewall" (a.k.a iptables/nftables) can be used for a lot of different things, one of which happens to be firewalling, this is not going to be an easy task. You can inspect the tables to see if rules have been added, but to tell whether they are "firewall" rules or something else is going to take a lot of work...

Answer (score 3):

Here's what `iptables` uses:

```
$ ldd /sbin/iptables
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffa69fe000)
libip4tc.so.0 => /lib/libip4tc.so.0 (0x00007fe53853c000)
libip6tc.so.0 => /lib/libip6tc.so.0 (0x00007fe538334000)
libxtables.so.7 => /lib/libxtables.so.7 (0x00007fe538127000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe537d67000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fe537b63000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe53875d000)
```

As you can see, that's `libip4tc`, `lipip6tc` and `libxtables`. However, they are not great for external interfaces. I suggest you instead call out to `iptables-save` and post-process the machine-readable output from that.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do this through a C program then this may solve your purpose :)

```
   chk_fw()
   {
      const char * cmd = "service iptables status";
      system(cmd);
   }
```

Output: `iptables: Firewall is not running.`

Comment: I would like to check your function because I don't know if its able to detect all rules from Firewalls

Comment: no it will not .. but if you want such then change `cmd` and get what you want

Comment: I've tested your function (in my Debian machine) and output shows: "iptables: unrecognized service"

Comment: Sorry My answer was for redhat thats what i pre-assumed ... you will find much info here regading debian firewalls [debian](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-shorewall-firewall-configuration/)  and [ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo)  you can put _shorewall_ OR _ufw_  in place _iptables_ whatever suitable in your test c program

Answer (score 1):

This needs a check on iptables and there is no library available for this.
"libiptc" can be used, but it is not for public interfaces.